What do the terms in this equation $$θ_{1}x_{1}+θ_{2}x_{2}+θ_{0}=0$$ represent?
I am currently learning ML from a course by MIT. I am from a non tech background and unable to understand some equations shown in this lecture of Linear Classifiers:

https://youtu.be/yOKDzd73KgM?t=57
https://youtu.be/yOKDzd73KgM?t=349

I would be very grateful if someone can explain me these equations in simple language. What does each of the terms in these equations represent?

Nice work on self-studying! To understand the equation you posted, let's go through the most basic concepts and eventually build up the linear separator mentioned in the video. A lot of these concepts might already be understood by you, so feel free to skip around.
Linear Equations
So before we get to the equation , let's identify a few basic concepts from middle-school/high-school math.
Remember the equation of a line on an XY-graph? Most of the time, it is expressed as:

where m is the slope, b is the y-intercept, and (x, y) are a pair of coordinate points that make the equation true. As long as the values on both sides of the equation are equal to one another after we do all of our arithmetic, we can state that this is the equation for a linear function (function being a similar word for equation).
For example, let's say we had the equation y=2x+1. If we were to take all the available x-points from our graph (-2 to 2), and apply them to our equation, we would get the image below:

Notice that this line is simply a visualization of the values you get when plugging all of your x-values to get your y-values:
-3 = 2(-2) + 1
-1 = 2(-1) + 1
1 = 2(0) + 1
3 = 2(1) + 1
5 = 2(2) + 1

Now, let's start applying some variable names from the video you posted.
Linear Seperator
Now, the convenient thing about maths is the fact that you can swap out variable names, and still ultimately have them express the exact same idea.
For example, if we wanted to model something like "ice cream sales vs temperature", we could use the linear equation y = 5x + 2 (where x is the temperature in Celsius and y is the dollar amount we get for that day).
However, it would be much more convenient if we renamed our variables to something like D for dollars and C for Celsius to get D = 5C + 2.
Notice that this is still a linear equation! Let's say we turn our (x, y) coordinate into (x1, x2) (x1 indicating predictor 1, x2 indicating predictor 2), and we use theta_1 (the "0" with the tail in the middle of it) for m and theta_0 for b.
Our linear equation would then turn into...

Notice that this is just a few steps away from what you originally posted! Using some basic addition/subtraction, do you see how we could get "0" on one side, and all the "x" terms on the other?

Even though the signs are off and we're missing a "theta_2" term, notice that this is just the same exact thing as a straight line (linear function)!
Keeping this in mind, watch the rest of the lecture and notice how the professor speaks about values that fall above this line and below this line. Sort of like a "separation" or "classification" of data-points.
Conclusion
Best of luck in your ML studies! A lot of ML is predicated on statistics. If you'd like to get a overview of basic college stats (and learn R at the same time), I highly recommend Danielle Navarro's Learning Statistics with R.. There are sections on setting up a psychology experiment in this book, but you can safely ignore it.
